# Delete last row of table in nested div

Tags: html, jquery-selectors, removechild

i want to delete last row.

i have dive within div , which has table and many rows.

i wanted to delete last row of table. i am unable to iterate to last tr.

```
  <div class="span15" id="MURWorksheetPage2">
                <div class="span8">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col1">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MedicineUseNo) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MedicineUseNo, new { id = "txtMedicineUseNo", style = "Width:20px" })

                            </td>
                            <td class="col2">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MedicinePrescribed) @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MedicinePrescribed, new { id = "txtMedicinePrescribed" })</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col1" colspan="2">
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OTC)  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OTC, new { id = "txtOTC" })

                            </td>
                        </tr>
 </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: whatever i had tried i deleted since last 2 hours i am struggling for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should work.

```
$('#MURWorksheetPage2 div table :last').remove();
```